# Loading data into UITableView, no data displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've got an issue getting an array into the tableview block which seems to run multiple times before the function to retrieve the data runs and once afterwards, I know the function returns the data but it doesn't make it to the tableview code.

The view controlller is based on another I have which does work.

Using Xcode 11 and I've gone through various other questions as well as various examples online but can't seem to find the cause of my problem.

The code is shown in 1 file but normally the function is in another file, result is the same.

As you can see the tableview section runs 3 times before the function and once afterwards, why would it return 3 times rather than once before the function? and why is the data not reaching the tableview code?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

struct order: Codable {
    var fuel_type_id: Int;
    var membership_number: Int;
    var order_id: Int;
    var price: String;
    var timestamp: String;
    var volume: Int;
}

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var history = NSArray()

    var membershipNumber = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            tableView.tableFooterView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self

            let db = Firestore.firestore()

            let docRef = db.collection("users").document(defaults.string(forKey: "uid")!)

                docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {

                        let membership_number = document.get("membership_number")
                        self.membershipNumber = membership_number as! Int


                        self.fetchOrders(membershipNumber: self.membershipNumber) { (Bool) in

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension HistoryViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
          return 1
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("line75 \(history)")
        return history.count
      }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
       return "Section"
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        print("cell /(cell!)")
        let order = history.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        print("line87 \(order)")
        let label = order["timestamp"] as! String
        cell?.textLabel?.text = label
            return cell!
            }
    }


extension HistoryViewController {

    func fetchOrders(membershipNumber: Int, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        let dictRequest : [String:String] = ["username":locUsername,"password":locPassword]
  WebHelper.requestGetResponseUrl(locBaseURL+"tbl_order?filter=membership_number,eq,\(membershipNumber)", dictParameter: dictRequest, controllerView: self, success: { (response) in
            if response.count == 0 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: Messages.ServerError, on: self)
                }
            } else {
                if let arrHistory = response["records"] as? NSArray {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("line97 \(arrHistory)")
                        if (arrHistory as AnyObject).count > 0 {
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(arrHistory, forKey: "history")
                            let history = arrHistory
                            print("line101 \(history)")
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            completion(true)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                GlobalConstant.showAlertMessage(withOkButtonAndTitle: GlobalConstant.AppName, andMessage: error?.localizedDescription ?? Messages.ServerError, on: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debug

```
line75 (
)
line75 (
)
line75 (
)
Server code 200
line97 (
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 31;
        price = "116.50";
        timestamp = "2013-09-03 13:27:01";
        volume = 2400;
    },
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 50;
        price = "111.60";
        timestamp = "2013-10-04 12:21:24";
        volume = 2000;
    },
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 65;
        price = "110.50";
        timestamp = "2013-11-05 17:09:02";
        volume = 2000;
    }
)
line101 (
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 31;
        price = "116.50";
        timestamp = "2013-09-03 13:27:01";
        volume = 2400;
    },
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 50;
        price = "111.60";
        timestamp = "2013-10-04 12:21:24";
        volume = 2000;
    },
        {
        "fuel_type_id" = 3;
        "membership_number" = 1;
        "order_id" = 65;
        price = "110.50";
        timestamp = "2013-11-05 17:09:02";
        volume = 2000;
    }
)
line75 (
)
```

Comment: Are you using Prototype Cells designed in Interface Builder? If yes you must **not** register the cell. And don't use `NSArray/NSDictionary` in Swift. Use native types.

Comment: Should removing the registering of the cell stop the tableview being called multiple times? (doesn't seem to have made any difference), I've created the array as     var history = [AnyObject]()  I am now looking at why it's empty in the tableview block

Comment: I see the issue. You have to assign the result to the data source array. Replace `let history = arrHistory` with `self.history = arrHistory`. And declare history as `[[String:Any]]` rather than `[AnyObject]`. In Swift be as type-specific as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working but it's very untidy, I'll go over it again using your comment and hopefully tidy it up, thanks for your help.